# how to sort a column by creating custom list in excel?

Tags: excel

I have a column in an excel file like this-

| Replication |
| --- |
| R1 |
| R1 |
| R1 |
| R2 |
| R2 |
| R2 |
| R3 |
| R3 |
| R3 |
| .. |

I want to sort this column like this-

| Replication |
| --- |
| R1 |
| R2 |
| R3 |
| R1 |
| R2 |
| R3 |
| R1 |
| R2 |
| R3 |
| .. |

How can I achieve this by using excel sort by creating a custom list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a helper column that counts the number of Replication above it.  Put this in the helper column:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2)
```

[image]

Then sort ascending both columns looking first at the sort column:

[image]

Then you can hide the sort column if you desire or delete it if the sort is just a one off.